# Cheapest way stay/travel in UK from India

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, india, budget

My friend and I are planning to go to the UK from India for a 15 day trip in next June from 3rd to 18th(have to be at Hampshire on 5th June, The Oval on 9th June, old Trafford 16th June), so right now I'm just doing my homework by assembling some of the points.

So I want to know, in India :

- what would be the process, what documents are required
- which Visa is required?
- How much amount should be there in your bank?

and in the UK :

- what are the possible cheaper options to stay?
- what are the mandatory things like a bus, train pass or something?
- Is there any other expense that I should cater?

Most importantly, what would be the best and cheaper ways to stay and travel inside the UK?

One good link that i found was [this](https://www.busbud.com/blog/cheapest-ways-travel-uk-bus-coach-vs-train/) but I'm looking for more information to be more confident.

Comment: This question does not fit this site. Some of your questions are already answered elsewhere on the site. The questions about which is best are too broad to answer since we don't know your preferences in enough detail.

Comment: @user16259 can you suggest the changes then please?

Comment: You can post multiple different questions on this site, each one focused on one subject. Example 'what is the cheapest way to travel between London and Manchester?'

Answer (score 1):

You need a standard visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa There is no defined amount for savings, you just have to be able to show a stable income with a surplus of income over expenditure and that the amount you’re proposing to spend on the trip is credible eg you’re not spending your entire life savings. There are a lot of questions about U.K. visas on this site, search ‘visa refusals’ to see the pitfalls.  In the U.K. a cheap accommodation option is AirBnB, however most hosts look for someone with an established profile / good reviews on the site, youth hostels are another option  https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/HotelsList-England-Youth-Hostels-zfp12073328.html  Travel by bus is generally cheaper than trains but takes longer https://www.checkmybus.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a [Oyster card](https://oyster.tfl.gov.uk/oyster/entry.do) at the airport and use it for daily bus/train travel. You might know that London is divided into various zonal area. You can travel to any zone with a [Daily Cap limit](https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/oyster/using-oyster/price-capping#on-this-page-1). I would suggest you to plan your all tourist activities as per zonal area to minimise your bus/train fares on each day. Because a single trip to zone 1 to 6 would increase the daily cap limit to £12.50. You can choose for backpack hostels as the cheapest accommodation option where you will also have the facility of cooking in hostel kitchens. Others option would be hotels/airbnb in non-prime zones which are comparatively cheaper than zone 1/2.

General rule for London:-  you will be able to get discount on ticket price if you book it online and carry the print of it. In my experience, the ticket counter prices are always £1-3 more expensive than online price.

Comment: Old Trafford is in Manchester, it’s accessible by train and bus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Trafford